# React Router props `location` / `match` not updating with `ConnectedRouter`

Tags: react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom, connected-react-router

I've got my app setup as in the docs:

## Step 1

```
...
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
...
const history = createBrowserHistory()

const store = createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(rootReducer), // new root reducer with router state
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      routerMiddleware(history), // for dispatching history actions
      // ... other middlewares ...
    ),
  ),
)
```

## Step 2

```
...
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router' // react-router v4
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
...
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}> { /* place ConnectedRouter under Provider */ }
      <div> { /* your usual react-router v4 routing */ }
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<div>Match</div>)} />
          <Route render={() => (<div>Miss</div>)} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('react-root')
)
```

I click on a `Link` or even `dispatch(push('/new-url/withparam'))`

However the props for `match` `location` are remaining the previous values or whatever the first page was.

What is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This one has bitten me many times.

*Your `Switch` and `Route` etc. MUST **NOT** BE INSIDE A CONNECTED COMPONENT!*

If the component is connected, the props for `match`, `location`, etc. don't seem to get updated and propagate down to your routes.

This means don't connect your top level `App` or `Root`, or any other nested containers between the `ConnectedRouter` and `Route`

--

Update:

You may just need to wrap your component with

```js
<Route render={ (routerProps) => <YourConnectedComponent { ...routerProps } />
```

Comment: THANKS. made my day.

Comment: Can you please post the example code as in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add example to here as I feel it is valuable input - even tho, it's already answered.

I had similar problem, when I pushed url into router history, it changed URL but it didn't navigate properly on the component I wanted. I googled and searched for answer for hours, until I found this thread which finally helped me to find out what I made wrong. So all credits to @ilovett.

So here is an example, if someone will need it for better understanding:

I had code similar to this:

```
export const routes =
    <Layout>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={ Component1 } />
            <Route path='/parameter1/:parameterValue' component={ Component2 } />
        </Switch>
    </Layout>;

<Provider store={ store }>
    <ConnectedRouter history={ history } children={ routes } />
</Provider>
```

It was working fine when I came to a project, but then I decided to refactor Layout component and I **connected it to the store** which caused that *Component2* stopped receiving correct values in the *ownProps.match.params.parameter1* and because of that it rendered component completely wrong.

So only thing what you need to do is move Layout outside of *ConnectedRouter*. Nothing between *ConnectedRouter* and *Route* can be connected to the store.

Working example is this then:

```
export const routes =
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={ Component1 } />
            <Route path='/parameter1/:parameterValue' component={ Component2 } />
        </Switch>;

<Provider store={ store }>
    <Layout>
        <ConnectedRouter history={ history } children={ routes } />
    </Layout>
</Provider>
```